# What is this paintComponent override meant to do?

Tags: java, swing

Disclaimer:  I do a lot of Java these days, but it's mostly data handling, algorithmic things, and very emphatically *not* graphics or UX stuff.  My idea of high-intensity video gaming is 8-bit Pong.

I've come across this snippet of code in an application.  I cannot figure out what problem this `paintComponent` is meant to solve.

```
JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(35) {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        Rectangle r = g.getClipBounds();
        g.fillRect (0, 0, r.width, r.height);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
```

It *looks* like it's trying to fill in some area with the current background color, but where the "clip bounds" are supposed to be, and why that wouldn't be happening already, is outside my experience.  Searching the rest of the source file for "clip" yielded nothing.

The code is fairly old -- written in the days of Java 1.5 -- but the application runs all the time under current JREs (Java 8 and 9 as of this writing).  There have never been any visual oddities reported with the password field in question.  The field is displayed in an otherwise boring JPanel.

The author of the code has long since left the company.  Actually, the author's replacement had left the company before I arrived.  I don't believe anyone involved with this section of code still works here, so nobody to ask.  (I get called in to do a lot of pinch-hitting for teams like this.)  I have found a lot of their old code to be cargo-cult-esque, in that they've copied it in from some random project elsewhere in the company, so this might be more of the same.

In the spirit of "poke it with a stick and see what breaks", I did some extremely basic fiddling:  replacing `getBackground()` with `Color.MAGENTA` to see if anything in the software turned violently pink, removing the anonymous subclass altogether to see if anything went pear-shaped, etc.  None of the changes seemed to make any visible difference on Windows.

Of course, absence of evidence versus evidence of absence and all that, I can't prove that it *isn't* needed on some platform somewhere.  But I'd like to add a comment saying what the author of old might have been trying to do...

Comment: Since one of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to typically paint the background, and in the case of a text based component, the text, the code seems to be doing, well, nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It looks like it's trying to fill in some area with the current background color, but where the "clip bounds" are supposed to be, and why that wouldn't be happening already, is outside my experience. Searching the rest of the source file for "clip" yielded nothing.

The "clip" is actually defined by the `Graphics` context and in most cases it is defined to the size of the component bounds anyway, although it can be used to increase the speed of painting in some scenarios, I wouldn't see a great deal of benefit for it here without more context

You can have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

> The code is fairly old -- written in the days of Java 1.5

I've been writing in Swing since 1.3 and never found the need to do anything like this

Since one of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to typically paint the background, and in the case of a text based component, the text, the code seems to be doing, well, nothing.

> have found a lot of their old code to be cargo-cult-esque, in that they've copied it in from some random project elsewhere in the company, so this might be more of the same.

This is probably a good assessment, it might have been used for trying to display placeholder text at some point and has been modified down to what you see now ... as a wild guess.

I think it's safe to say you can remove it without out any side effects

Comment: That's a handy link, definitely keeping that around for further study.  Cheers!